# Application with the same package but with a different signature

Tags: android, android-studio, keystore, signature, android-keystore

I upgraded my Android studio to 1.4. Now when I'm deploying my app to my device I get the message that the device has an application with the same package but a different signature. How is this possible? I already did some research and I looked up my *debug.keystore*, but this hasn't changed since 13/03/2015. Anyone has any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: can you show the screen shot of the message

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-zEsM8lFFUMA/VjHTjpcMRUI/AAAAAAAABCU/6QI-N21TRTA/w674-h216-no/different%2Bsignature.PNG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug builds are signed with the SDK keystore which is generated when you install the Android SDK. On Linux / OSX it is located at `~/.android/debug.keystore`.
The message you had means that you have a debug build installed and you want to install an App Store build on it (or the other way around).
This can also happen when you deploy from a different machine.

Comment: The weird thing is that I'm still on the same computer with the same debug.keystore. I never made or used an other key for this application.

Comment: Older versions of Android Studio did have the Android SDK installed for themselves. So if you just upgraded from a relativily old version, than maybe that might be the issue. Otherwise you can just discard the message, and delete the old app, since it is your app and your device there are no risks. If it was a publicly used device and a banking application, then I would be suspicious :-)

Comment: Some other people are using this app aswell. But I guess I'll just give them a call to delete it and install the update manually. Thank you very much for the quick answering!

Comment: Not sure if you have to. If they install via the Google Play, the signature is always the same (that's how Google makes sure that no one can update your application), so they won't see this message. If they install via the APK, then they might run into the same problem you are having.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. I just gave them the apk. It didn't go through the Google Play Store :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the keys that have been used to sign the `APKs`, by default if you are running directly from your IDE and opening your Emulator, the APK installed in the Emulator is signed with your debug-key(usually installed in `~/.android/debug.keystore)`, so if the previous APK was signed with a different key other than the one you are currently using you will always get the signatures conflict, in order to fix it, make sure you are using the very same key to sign both `APKs`, even if the previous `APK` was signed with a debug-key from another `SDK`, the keys will definitely be different.

Also if you don't know exactly what key was used before to sign the apk and yet you want to install the new version of your app, you can just uninstall the previous application and reinstall the new one.

for more info go through [This](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Hope this Helps...

Comment: The weird thing is that I'm still on the same computer with the same debug.keystore. I never made or used an other key for this application.